# C# WPF Menu not displaying first "_" in header

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I am trying to dynamically populate the headers of MenuItems based on filenames the MenuItem will open when clicked. I've found that whenever a header name has one or more "_"'s the first one is never displayed.

I'm trying to determine the best workaround for this problem. I could replace the first "_" with "__" but I was wondering if there was a better solution?

The following is an example of my code

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuTest" 
          Header="this_is_a_Test">
</MenuItem>
```

which produces a header that looks like "thisis_a_test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Header content with a more complex control, not just a string:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="MenuTest">
    <MenuItem.Header>
         <TextBlock Text="this_is_a_test"/>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: This was a much simpler solution to implement which worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Underscores in the Header properties usually used for shorty cuts (like Ctrl+O for open, the header would be _Open). I believe to work around this just use two underscores for that first underscore in the header or you could could change the under lying template but that’s much more complex.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I've been trying to figure out if _ was some kind of special character for awhile now